# Should I ask here about an academic paper on indexing?

Tags: discussion

I'm researching bitmap indexes for an MSc assignment.

A good early paper on the topic is "[Bit Transposed Files](http://www.vldb.org/conf/1985/P448.PDF)" by Wong et al, published in 1985.

I find the paper's description of Composite Encoding a little unclear, and would like some help to understand it.

Is this a good place to ask such a question?

Can you point me to existing questions or advice that I should follow in asking such a question?

If this is not a good place, is there a more appropriate place? The [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) seems to love stuff like this.

Comment: I think that'd be on-topic, I'd say go for it and we can assess as we go along: thanks for asking first :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Should database theory questions be posted here, in cstheory or in cs?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/941/should-database-theory-questions-be-posted-here-in-cstheory-or-in-cs). Its accepted answer suggests it's okay for me to ask such a question, as long as it's objective and fits in the FAQ. The FAQ doesn't mention academic papers explicitly.

Comment: I posted my question: [How to decode a query on a composite unary-encoded attribute?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41714/how-to-decode-a-query-on-a-composite-unary-encoded-attribute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES.

Comment: What emphatic encouragement!